# Problem with setting cte max recursion depth value using raw sql in EF Core

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, recursion, common-table-expression

Not able to set the cte max recursion depth value using raw sql with db parameterization.

I am using MySql database and have few programs which uses recursive cte's. I am trying to set the max cte recursion depth value from the code using raw sql with db parameters but its not working as expected.
I am following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursion-limits to set the max cte recursion value as part of the cte query.

Here is the code for the same -

```
var cteString = @"WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte
)
SELECT /*+ SET_VAR(cte_max_recursion_depth = {0}) */ * FROM cte";

result = await this.DbContext
                        .Set<TEntity>()
                        .FromSqlRaw(cteString, new object[] { 10 })
                        .CountAsync(cancelToken) > 0;
```

For some reason, its not working (no errors thrown, but default cte_max_recursion_depth is used instead). It works just fine if I hardcode the max recursion depth value instead of parametrizing it. It also works if I use interpolated string.
I really want to use parametrized way to set the value as its a recommended approach. Any help would be appreciated.

**Provider details -**

- EF Core version: 6.0.2
- Database provider: (e.g. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)
- Target framework: (e.g. .NET 6.0)
- IDE: (e.g. Visual Studio 2022 17.0.3)

Comment: Could you run an SQL statement with 'SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = X;' before running your CTE?